# Passing a C file to setup.py by relative path

Tags: python, setup.py

How can I pass the relative path of hello.c file in my setup.py script?
The below code is not working when using '../code/Hello.c'. I am getting error 
atal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
The bug is not reproducible, so it is likely a hardware or OS problem

For example: I am running this script in the directory `script/` and hello.c is present in the directory `code/`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
module1 = Extension('Hello', sources = ['../code/Hello.c'])

Setup (name = 'PackageName',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'This is a demo package',
    ext_modules = [module1])
```

Comment: is this not working ? Are you getting any errors ? Could you be more specific about the problems that you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass on relative paths to your source file in the Extension class. However, that is not really a recommended approach. It is a good idea to make sure that you write setup.py at the root level of your source directory tree and your references are below that. In that case, the relative paths that you specify, using the unix path separator, remain platform agnostic as well.

Comment: I am doing like this module1 = Extension('Hello', sources = ['../code/Hello.c']) .

Comment: As I don't have access to root dirctory in linux  , running the python setup.py command from other directory where i have coded the hello.c code . its giving the error when using relatives path .

Comment: I hope you have access to the folder which contains setup.py, in that case, just create `code/Hello.c` and then run setup.py

Comment: I can do that .but I have to maintain the particular directory structure .thats why want to use [../code/Hello.c].